# Orbit Slider and Events Manager Plug-in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, wp-enqueue-script

I have this slider(orbit slider http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/orbit.php ) and a wordpress plugin(event manager http://wp-events-plugin.com/ ) that loads all this jQuery-ui stuff(

```
/**
   * Enqueing public scripts and styles
   */
  function public_enqueue() {
    //Scripts
    wp_enqueue_script('events-manager', plugins_url('includes/js/events-manager.js',__FILE__), array('jquery', 'jquery-ui-core','jquery-ui-widget','jquery-ui-position','jquery-ui-sortable','jquery-ui-datepicker','jquery-ui-autocomplete','jquery-ui-dialog')); //jQuery will load as dependency
    //Styles
    wp_enqueue_style('events-manager', plugins_url('includes/css/events_manager.css',__FILE__)); //main css
  }

  /**
   * Localize the script vars that require PHP intervention, removing the need for inline JS.
   */
  function localize_script(){
    global $em_localized_js;
    $locale_code = substr ( get_locale(), 0, 2 );
    //Localize
    $em_localized_js = array(
      'ajaxurl' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php'),
      'locationajaxurl' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php?action=locations_search'),
      'firstDay' => get_option('start_of_week'),
      'locale' => $locale_code,
      'dateFormat' => get_option('dbem_date_format_js'),
      'ui_css' => plugins_url('includes/css/ui-lightness.css', __FILE__),
      'show24hours' => get_option('dbem_time_24h'),
      'is_ssl' => is_ssl(),
    );
```

) on the very top of every page on the site(

```
<link rel='stylesheet' id='events-manager-css'  href='http://at.theplural.com/wp-content/plugins/events-manager/includes/css/events_manager.css?ver=3.4.2' type='text/css' media='all' />
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://at.theplural.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/ui/jquery.ui.core.min.js?ver=1.8.20'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://at.theplural.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/ui/jquery.ui.widget.min.js?ver=1.8.20'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://at.theplural.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/ui/jquery.ui.position.min.js?ver=1.8.20'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://at.theplural.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/ui/jquery.ui.mouse.min.js?ver=1.8.20'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://at.theplural.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/ui/jquery.ui.sortable.min.js?ver=1.8.20'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://at.theplural.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/ui/jquery.ui.datepicker.min.js?ver=1.8.20'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://at.theplural.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/ui/jquery.ui.autocomplete.min.js?ver=1.8.20'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://at.theplural.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/ui/jquery.ui.resizable.min.js?ver=1.8.20'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://at.theplural.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/ui/jquery.ui.draggable.min.js?ver=1.8.20'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://at.theplural.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/ui/jquery.ui.button.min.js?ver=1.8.20'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://at.theplural.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/ui/jquery.ui.dialog.min.js?ver=1.8.20'></script>
```

) . I'm basically trying to block that javascript from loading on the front page, or ideally, loading on only the specific page it's needed on -> page('events'). I tried my best to 'dequeue' the js, but it's not working

Comment: Please use the "edit" link and format your code (The WYSIWG editor got buttons for that).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to enqueue the scripts only on the "Events" page, change the following code to include the conditional tag `is_page()`

```
function public_enqueue() {
    //Scripts
    wp_enqueue_script('events-manager', plugins_url('includes/js/events-manager.js',__FILE__), array('jquery', 'jquery-ui-core','jquery-ui-widget','jquery-ui-position','jquery-ui-sortable','jquery-ui-datepicker','jquery-ui-autocomplete','jquery-ui-dialog')); //jQuery will load as dependency
    //Styles
    wp_enqueue_style('events-manager', plugins_url('includes/css/events_manager.css',__FILE__)); //main css
}
```

Change it to the following:

```
function public_enqueue() {
    if( is_page('events') ) { //Only load on the page "events"
        //Scripts
        wp_enqueue_script('events-manager', plugins_url('includes/js/events-manager.js',__FILE__), array('jquery', 'jquery-ui-core','jquery-ui-widget','jquery-ui-position','jquery-ui-sortable','jquery-ui-datepicker','jquery-ui-autocomplete','jquery-ui-dialog')); //jQuery will load as dependency
        //Styles
        wp_enqueue_style('events-manager', plugins_url('includes/css/events_manager.css',__FILE__)); //main css
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. The only problem with what I see above is that there are several 'events' pages(am i right?), and that I would have to modify the plugin code. This is what I have in functions.php right now. It works for now, but it is loading on litterally every page but home. http://pastie.org/5423274

Comment: Well, I don't know how your site is built up. But I thought you where asking to only show it on the page "events", which this code does. Maybe you could share a link?

I haven't used that event-plugin. But I'm guessing that it creates some sort of Custom Post Type for the events, so you could extend the IF-statement to include that post type `if( is_page('events') || is_singular( 'post-type-name' ) )`(replace "post-type-name" with the name of the event post type name.)